# Responding to user input with PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'll have a PowerPoint page on the screen that says:

> Name the top most spoken languages

The audience then yells out and tells me what they think they are, and when they guess one, I need to display the one they guessed under the question, and continue the process until they have guessed all three.

> Name the top most spoken languages
>
> - Chinese
> - Spanish
> - English

However, I don't know in which order they will guess the answers.

How can I display the answers in whatever order the audience supplies them?

Comment: Why the markdown and close vote?  I expect this is a very common need, however, I have searched and cannot find how to do so.  Suppose I can create six pages (! 3x2x1) and have links to all, but this is a horrible solution.  Maybe I can hide text and have a link which displays it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge you can accomplish so by setting up *Trigger* until certain conditions are satisfied. Anyway rather than wasting time let's start the steps:

**Step 1:** First Enable your '**Selection Pan**' from "**Home**" *menu bar* by clicking on "**Arrange**" *drop-down arrow* then "**Selection Pane**".
**Step 2:** Then off-course you need a prepared slide with Questions and Options in it.
**Step 3:** Now you need to have the *Option Numbering* & the *Option* created using separate '*WordArt*' or '*Text Box*'.
**Step 4:** Now from '**Animations**' menu give an *Animation Effect* to the *Options* not the corresponding *Option Numbers*.
**Step 5:** After that select First *Option Number* and you will notice its corresponding *Rectangle Number* will highlight in '**Selection Pane**' remember the *Rectangle Number*.
 [image] 
**Step 6:** Now Select the corresponding *Option* to the *Option Number* (make sure you have already assigned an *Animation Effect* to the *Option*, not the *Option Number*).
**Step 7:** And in the '**Animations**' menu click on the "**Trigger**" *drop-down arrow* then "**On Click of**" and *Select* the **Rectangle Number** of the *Option* - *Option Number*.
[You can also use "*On-Bookmark*" Option in "*Trigger*" if you have created Bookmark].
 [image] 
**Step 8:** Now define '*Trigger*' for all your *Options* by its corresponding *Option Number*.
**Step 9:** Now whenever One will give answer to the Question and the answer is correct then off-course you know the answer is in which Option Number just click on the Option Number during *Slide Show* and the *Option* (answer) will appear.
[*However it is difficult to remember which Option is present in which Option Number - Anyway you asked and I know a method that's why I explained*]
**Step 10:** Now why are you waiting for *Play & Enjoy* your *Slide Show*.

**Done!**

Comment: Thanks RK.  Very compressive answer! I had stumbled upon triggers when researching possible solutions, however, was uncertain whether they would work.  Good to know they can be done!  Ended up going old-school today, and presented this with a whiteboard and pen.